# Removing viewcontrollers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory, uiviewcontroller

I have two controllers in the my application with tableviews. 
Each tableview has many images with high quality. So, the application eats a lot of memory (for example on the first controller about 350). When I go to the second viewcontroller, the application starts to eat about 600 Mb of memory. When I come back to the first controller, application starts to eat about 850 Mb of memory. I tried to watch deinitialization of controllers, but there are no theirs deinitialization. They are always in the memory and every opening of controller creates new page, but old page are not removed. But why? Could me say me somebody what I do wrong?

Comment: You need to post the code you have written for the controllers.

Comment: If you're using segues to move between the viewcontollers note that normal segues always create a new destination VC. You should use an *unwind segue* to return to the first viewcontroller.

Comment: Dismiss/pop/unwind from the second controller to get back to the first view controller. Or use a different technique altogether such as tab view controller or page view controller to jump between the two view controllers. We can’t say without seeing the logical relationship between the two view controllers.

Comment: Also, when you’re done fixing the jumping between the two view controllers, you might want to look at what they are doing that is taking 300mb each. If you show us what they’re doing, we might be able of offer ways to reduce that memory footprint. E.g., are you loading lots of images but not resizing them for dimensions of respective image views? Are you loading a lot of images before they’re really required by the UI? Etc.(Though, this might best be a sepaerate question you post only after the first problem is solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationViewController must have **Is Initial View Controller** option in true position.